# Oauth refresh token funcionando inconsistentemente

Tags: asp.net, oauth, refreshtoken, owin

He implementado Refresh Token para refrescar access_token usando el enlace http://www.advancesharp.com/blog/1236/asp-net-web-api-2-owin-oauth-bearer-token-refresh-token-with-custom-database. Cuando utilizo tiempos de expiración bajos para probar la implementación, por ejemplo 1 minuto para access_token y 2 minutos para refresh_token funciona perfectamente, pero cuando cambio los tiempos de expiración 20 y 40 minutos respectivamente rara vez funciona si intento refrescar el token una vez que el access_token ha expirado (Después de 20 minutos). ¿Podrías guiarme en qué me estoy equivocando?

Gracias